# PDF created in Adobe LiveCycle Designer does not open

Tags: adobe-reader, livecycle-designer

I designed a editable PDF in Adobe LiveCycle Designer.
Customers complain that PDF does not open and displays the following message:

> Please wait...  If this message is not eventually replaced by the
>   proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to
>   display this type of document.  You can upgrade to the latest version
>   of Adobe Reader for Windows, Mac, or Linux by  visiting
>   http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download.  For more assistance with
>   Adobe Reader visit http://www.adobe.com/go/acrreader.

I personally walked down to check and they are using the most recent updates too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
Customer was trying to open editable PDF in browser.

Asked customer to download and then open. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux you cannot open even after downloading the file. I get complains about forms used.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but if anyone else comes across this issue, if you are using Life Cycle try saving your form as a static PDF.

Save as>> Adobe Static PDF Form

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer by @terminator

You can force the document to download on modern browser with the [html download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

```
<a href='example.pdf' download>Example</a>
```